# How to use sum function in where clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sum

I am new to SQL Server. I want to equal two columns using `sum` function. Please find the below query.

```
select top 1000 
    o.orderamount, sum(oi.amount), oi.orderid 
from 
    orders o 
inner join 
    orderitem oi on o.orderid = oi.orderid 
where 
    orderamount = sum(oi.amount)
group by  
    oi.orderid, orderamount
order by 
    oi.orderid desc
```

Whenever I execute this code, I get an error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just use [HAVING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql):

```
select  top 1000 o.orderamount, sum(oi.amount), oi.orderid 
from orders o 
inner join orderitem oi on o.orderid = oi.orderid 
group by oi.orderid ,orderamount
HAVING orderamount = sum(oi.amount)
order by oi.orderid desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
select  top 1000 o.orderamount, oi.amount, oi.orderid 
from orders o 
inner join (select orderid, sum(amount) amount from orderitem group by orderid) orderitem 
oi on o.orderid = oi.orderid and orderamount = oi.amount
order by oi.orderid desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using HAVING instead of WHERE clauses in sum queries.
Also: add indentation and UPPER CASE for readability

```
SELECT TOP 1000  o.OrderAmount, sum(oi.Amount), oi.OrderID 
  FROM  Orders o 
        INNER JOIN OrderItem oi ON oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
  GROUP BY  oi.OrderID, OrderAmount
    HAVING  OrderAmount = sum(oi.Amount)
  ORDER BY  oi.OrderID DESC;
```